# Moshi is not mapping null values in Map

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

Let's say that we have a class that contains only one property:

```
data class MyClass(val map: Map<String, String?>)
```

As you can see, `map` property may contain `null` values, e.g.:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": null
}
```

Now if I use this instance of adapter to create JSON:

```
moshi.adapter(MyClass::class.java)
```

It will skip entries with `null` values (for the example above it will return a `String` like this: `{ "key1": "value1" }`). The same thing happens if I add `.serializeNulls()` to the adapter instance.

**Question**

How can I force a Moshi adapter to take `null` into consideration?

Comment: Adding serializeNulls() works for me. Here's a test case to demonstrate. https://pastebin.com/raw/B5bXdbwr Can you provide a failing test case to show what you mean?